# Recursive function that sums the first n recriprocals

Tags: java, recursion

The function below accepts an integer n and returns the sum of the first n reciprocals. 
sum(2) should return 1.5

Here is what I have:

```
 public double sum(int n) {

     if (n < 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Power Argument");
    }

    double zero = 0.0; 

    if(n == 0)
       return zero; 

    else
       return (1/n) + sum(n-1);   
 }
```

I am almost certain that this should work but instead it's returning 1.0 for basically everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using integer division. Cast it to a double:

```
return (1/(double)n) + sum(n-1);
```

Alternatively, use:

```
return (1.0/n) + sum(n-1);
```

Comment: perfect. i figured it had something to do with passing in an integer. thanks

Comment: @kachilous: It is a very common mistake, but easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`(1/n)` is integer division - use `(1.0/n)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
return (1.0/n) + sum(n-1);
```